# jQuery Dynamic DOM Selector Pattern possible?

Tags: jquery, variables, dynamic, design-patterns

In jQuery we usually use, for example:

```
var content = $('tr#someid td').find('div').html();
var content = $('tr#someid div').has('p').text();
var content = $('tr#someid td:eq(1) div').html();
```

Is it possible to make the `right part` of dollar sign `$` dynamic?

```
// Pattern Array
var pattern = [
    "('tr#someid td').find('div').html()",
    "('tr#someid div').has('p').text()",
    "('tr#someid td:eq(1) div').html()"
];

var contents = "";
for (i=0; i<pattern.length; i++) {
    /*
     * I WANT TO GRAB THE ELEMENTS HERE!
     * SOMETHING LIKE:
     */
     var dynamic_var = pattern[i];
     contents += $dynamic_var;
}
```

Is it possible?
So the problem is:

- Can we make the Variable Variable in jQuery Selector?
- Like: `$_______________;` ?
- The blank `_________` will be a dynamic pattern variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you could use `eval`, please check the **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/krKUY/1/)**

```
<div id="div">This is a div</div>
<input type="button" value="show" id="show" />​

var arr = ['("#div")'];
$('#show').click(function(){
    eval('$'+arr[0]);
});
```

​Not really sure if this will serve your purpose but hope this help.